# Can I copy the Windows upgrade from one PC to another?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

I have multiple PCs eligible for the 8.1 upgrade.

They are all the same version of Windows 8.  Can I copy the 3 gig update from one computer to the next?

I have a gigabit network and it just makes more sense to copy it that way than to download all three updates.

Answer (score 1):

Is the update just an exe file?  If so yes you can do it.  You can create a network share and access it from the other computers and run it directly from the share or put it on a thumb drive.

I found an article explaining how to easily install the Windows 8.1 update on several computers.    http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57608376-285/how-to-download-the-official-microsoft-windows-8.1-iso/

I was going to write my own instructions but I am not big on reinventing the wheel.  :)

Comment: He asked a question without giving a lot of details.  Do you expect me to explain in detail  how to share files between computers or how to copy files to a thumb drive?  I will admit my answer could have been more through but technically it does answer the question being asked.

Comment: Better.  I removed the -1 and my initial comment.  In regards to the article, only 1 poster was successful.  I have one pc left so I will try it later and see if I have success.  If I do, will mark as answer.

Comment: I have not had success following the instructions here; though the comments for this article indicate others have.  I'm pretty sure I have the 8.1 ISO because it says "Windows 8.1 Install".  However, of all places, I am stuck at entering the "cd key".  I used a [Key Finder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) to obtain the current Windows 8 on the system, but it tells me the key is not compatible with the install.  Out of frustration, I am just getting it 8.1 from the Windows store so I can be done with it.

Comment: Keep in mind your original question was about file sharing, not finding your cd key for windows 8.

Comment: You're killing me.  My original question (which has not changed mind you) was about copying the Windows 8.1 upgrade from one computer to another. You read it as "how do I copy a file from one computer to another."  That's just poor comprehension on your part.  Plus, your original answer did nothing more than regurgitate a Windows 101 tip any basic PC user should know.  I gave you the benefit of the doubt when you linked that article but, let's be honest, you didn't even know yourself if it worked. So don't try to defend your original answer.  It was awful and deserved -1.